# search string in files and replace it incrementally

Tags: search, replace, kate

I have a directory with 152 files named `plot_1` to `plot_152`.

In each of those there's some `R` code with some index `[[i]]`.

Using `Kate`version 15.08.2, is it possible to search for `[[i]]` in each file and replace it with the `[[1]]` for `plot_1` .... `[[152]]` for `plot_152`?

If not possible in `Kate`, is it possible using `bash`?

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
for i in {1...152}
do
    sed -i.bak -e "s/[[i]]/[[$i]]/g plot_$i
done
```

This script will run `sed` on each file, and backup them before replacing the string.

Answer (score 0):

Did a little tweak to `purplepsycho` solution:

```
for i in {1..152}
do
    sed -i.bak -e "s/[[i]]/[[$i]]]/g" plot_vents_$i
done
```